# Write Access when connecting to Mac Share from Raspberry pi

Tags: macos, mount, raspberry-pi

I am trying to access a shared drive from my Mac on my Raspberry Pi.  I am able to access and mount the drive and see the files but I am unable to make any changes or write files to the mounted drive.  Any ideas?

I'm mounting the drive with the following line of code:

```html
sudo mount -t cifs -v -rw -o username=pi,password=<witheld> //192.168.0.14/Turntable /home/pi/TurntableRemote/
```

As I said, it works fine to mount and view files but I am unable to make changes.  I created a new user for sharing only on my mac and then gave it read/write permissions to that folder.  I also tried connecting using my main username/password and I get the same thing.

I'm hoping there is a simply answer and I just missed something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have solved this by adding a uid value to the options.  The new code, if anyone is interested is below.

```
sudo mount -t cifs -v -rw -o username=pi,password=<witheld>,uid=pi //192.168.0.14/Turntable /home/pi/TurntableRemote/
```